# Populate the textbox if oninput is taking too long

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an event(oninput for a textbox) to compare it with certain text. This is not a server call.  But the event response is getting delayed due to lot of processing(5 secs). The issue is, till the 5 secs passes, the char which i typed doesn't show up on the textbox. When the oninput function completes it shows the char(i.e. after 5 secs).

As a solution, i want the text to appear first (whichever i type) and then later call event function.

```
MyGridView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
       'input input#EmailTxtBox': 'emailTextChanged'
 },

 emailTextChanged: function() {
        //offline search through already fetched data
        //no server call
 }
});
```

There is no question of sync/async call becase i have already fetched the data in another function, and i m just searching through this data. Also i have to handle input from keyboard and mouse, so specifically chose for oninput event. I am free to use any functions available in underscore & backbone. Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As someone already mentioned, the issue is probably a synchronous ajax call. You should post code related to ajax call, as well as your ajax settings. Or if you must use synchronous call for some reason, you should mention that in the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I assume is happening is your `emailTextChanged` function is making a call to some API **synchronously**.

The issue is a synchronous fetch will immediately block the UI until it has returned - which is why you're experiencing a delay between typing something and it showing up in your textbox.

To avoid blocking the UI, you should make this fetch asynchronously and use the 
`complete` callback to do the things.

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://yourendpoint',
   async: true,
   complete: function(data){
      // Do the things
   }
});
```

NB: With ajax, asynchronous is the default behaviour. However, the behaviour of all ajax requests can be defined by setting options in `$.ajaxSetup` - check `async: false` is not being set somewhere else unbeknownst to you.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: Thanks Stevie for your reply. I am using Backbone.js for this. I will try to implement async call in that.

Comment: No problem, if you need help just post the code you're using to do the fetch! Are you using a model or collection?

Comment: jQuery ajax is async by default. No need of `async: true,`

Comment: You're quite right but I thought I'd be explicit since I don't know the root cause (perhaps it had been set to false in $.ajaxSetup for example)